# Get and show a sum of from a column in Vue through an API

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

I have an API that returns the the sum from a column in mysql. I am getting the data json encoded. I want to show the data with Vue JS.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ROUND(SUM(total_amount), 2) as TotalAmount FROM orders");

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);
```

The result of of the json is

```
{
    "TotalAmount": "2645.09"
}
```

I am using Vue Js to get that data and passing it to a div.

```
 <div id="app" class="peer">
      <span>{{ TotalAmount }}</span>
</div>

<script>

  new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api_url.php')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})
</script>
```

I am not getting a the sum in my div. Vue developer tools is not working either for me to see if I am actually getting the value. Should i be doing the api a different way?

Comment: I think it should be `<span>{{ info }}</span>`

Comment: U are writing TotalAmount inside the div as variable but where did u difine it ! As Boussadjra Brahim said the solution to this is use info or instead of `this.info` use `this.TotalAmount`...also don't forget it to define in data function !

Comment: it shows the entire json @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: pleaase show me a screenshot of that object

Comment: thanks very much @BoussadjraBrahim. {{ info.TotalAmount }} worked. That was after I changed .then(response => (this.info = response)) to .then(response => (this.info = response.data))

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you are setting info with the result of `axios.get(...)` the result of your REST call is `response = { TotalAmount: "2645.09" }`

You have several problemes here:

1. When you write `then(response => (this.info = response))` info is not equal to the REST call response, but to the object returned by axios. if you want info to be equal to the REST call data, you need to set info with `response.data` or using object destructuring (`then({ data } => (this.info = data))`)
2. In your template you refer only to `TotalAmount` which is not a known attribut of your component

Update your component like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span>{{ totalAmount }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      info: undefined,
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://api_url.php');
    this.info = data;
  },
  computed: {
    totalAmount() {
      return this.info?.TotalAmount;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here I used a computed property `totalAmount` in order to avoid error like 'Cannot read property TotalAmount of undefined'

Comment: Maybe add also `<span v-if="totalAmount">` for more control over the DOM rendering.